# Attempting to move Files but unable to move Folders via Python

Tags: python

I am trying to move files and folders from directory to another. I am currently facing two issues.

1. It only seems to move files but not any folders.
2. It only picks up the uppercase or lowercase.

Do you know what might be missing to do this. I could add an `or` statement statement with `startswith` but would like to see if there is a better way to do this.

```
import os
from os import path
import shutil

src = "C:/Users/test/documents/"
dst = "C:/Users/test/Documents/test"

files = [i for i in os.listdir(src) if i.startswith("C") and \
         path.isfile(path.join(src, i))]
for f in files:
    shutil.move(path.join(src, f), dst)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I do understand what you mean with `2. It only picks up the uppercase or lowercase.`
Can you give an example.

Windows cannot have two files with the same name where only the case is different.

So it is impossible to have `test.txt` and `Test.txt` in the same directory.

If you just mean, that files with 'C' are copied and files with 'c' aren,t, then just do
`if i.lower().startswith("c")`

Comment: if you want to move files and directories, then do `if path.exists()` instead of `if path.isfile()`

Comment: Thanks Gelonida, this is what I was after. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will go through the source directory, create any directories that do not yet exist in the destination directory, and move the files from the source to the destination directory:

(As I understand it, this is what you want)

```
import os
import shutil

src = "C:/Users/test/documents/"
dst = "C:/Users/test/documents/test"

for src_dir, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
    dst_dir = src_dir.replace(src, dst, 1)
    if not os.path.exists(dst_dir):
        os.makedirs(dst_dir)
    for file_ in files:
        src_file = os.path.join(src_dir, file_)
        dst_file = os.path.join(dst_dir, file_)
        if os.path.exists(dst_file):
            os.remove(dst_file)
        shutil.move(src_file, dst_dir)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I will test this. This is not something I thought about in terms of directories not being created so could work a treat.